# Is there a way to let an object call a function after ist own destruction? [python3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, callback, del

I want a callback function on `del object`

---

#### Explanation

I have a `Player` Class.

And a `Player` can have objects of `Card` in his `Player.hand = []`

`Card` instances can be destroyed via `del <card_instance>`

If a `Player` has no `Cards` in his `hand` , the game is over.

To check that only when necessary, I want a `Card` to call a `Player.check_status()` fuction, that checks if the game is over **after its own destruction**.

Is that possible?

---

#### Code

```
class Player:
     self.hand = [...<Cards>...]

    def check_status(self):
         if self.hand == []:
             print("--- GAME OVER ---")

class Card:
     self.player = <Player_instance>

     def __del__(self):
          del self
          self.player.check_status() # <----- I want to do something like this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your object is tied to some external state that needs cleanup no matter what (like a file handle/socket), using `__del__` usually isn't the right choice. It's a sign you might be doing something wrong. For example if you wrapped your `del` in a `try...except`, then do something else assuming the hand has been changed you'd be wrong. Objects can be (temporarily) kept alive by a `try..except` block. `del card` is *not* the same thing as `card.__del__()`, it does NOT guarantee `__del__` will be called.

Likewise, usually you want your parent to manage it's children, not the other way around. Player's control their cards, cards don't control the player.

Just be explicit with your actions:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)

    def remove_card(self, card):
        self.hand.remove(card)
        if not self.hand:
            print('--- GAME OVER ---')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you count the number of cards right after every move and if number of cards equates to 0 then raise your Game Over status.

I am thinking:

1. Define a function counting the number of cards on hand.
2. Create a conditional statement that checks if card on hand is equal to 0.
3. Create a game over function that has the ability to restart game.